# The google_places function in googleway package throws an error

Tags: r, googleway

This happens when i use the google_places function

```
google_places(search_string = "Agence societe Generale, Paris 75015",
              key = key ,curl_proxy =curl_proxy("https://google.com"))

Error in downloadData(map_url, simplify, curl_proxy) :
Can not retrieve results. No valid internet connection (tested using curl::has_internet
```

Comment: The error says you have no valid internet connection. Are you sure you're online? Any reason you needed to set a proxy?

Comment: Thanks @camille for the reply. If i use without proxy still the same error. I have internet working

google_places(search_string = "Emergency Hospitals",
                     location = c(as.numeric(input$latitude), as.numeric(input$longitude)),
                     radius = 1000,
                     simplify = T)

Comment: Can you run the command `curl::has_internet()`, and do you get the same error?